# Symfony2 ManyToMany embedded forms unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

I have the following code which is working, the only problem I've found is when I create/edit a `cliente` and append/remove a `servicio` from it, instead of linking me the id of the existing `servicio` it creates another one, I explain here.

`cliente: foo. id: 1`

`service: bar. id: 1`

I go to the form, select `foo` and  `bar`, when I submit, I want to have on the table `clientes_servicios` which handles the relationships this data:

```
cliente_id      servicio_id
    1               1
```

Instead, what I'm getting is this:

```
cliente_id      servicio_id
    1               2
```

If I go to table `servicios` i see that Symfony2 has created another servicio with name `bar` but id `2` instead of using the existing servicio `bar` with id `1`

So what I want is to use the existing `servicio` and **never** create a new `servicio` from `cliente` form (because I have another form JUST for Servicio)

**Cliente form**

```
<?php
namespace Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ClientesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre')
            ->add('servicio', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new ServiciosType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    // Post Update
                    'by_reference' => false
        ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Clientes',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pge_incidenciasbundle_clientestype';
    }
}
```

**Servicio form**

```
<?php

namespace Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class ServiciosType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'PgeIncidenciasBundle:Servicios'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pge_incidenciasbundle_serviciostype';
    }
}
```

**Cliente Controller**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity  = new Clientes();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ClientesType(), $entity);
        $form->submit($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clientes_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('PgeIncidenciasBundle:Clientes:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Clientes entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Clientes();

        $form   = $this->createForm(new ClientesType(), $entity);

        return $this->render('PgeIncidenciasBundle:Clientes:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

**Cliente yml**

```
Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Clientes:
    type: entity
    table: clientes
    id:
      id:
        type: integer
        generator:
          strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nombre:
            type: string
            length: 250
            fixed: false
            nullable: true   
    manyToMany:
        servicio:
            targetEntity: Servicios
            cascade: [persist]
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Servicio YML**

```
Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios:
    type: entity
    table: servicios
    id:
      id:
        type: integer
        generator:
          strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nombre:
            type: string
            length: 250
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Cliente Entity**

```
<?php

namespace Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Clientes
 */
class Clientes
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $servicio;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->servicio = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Clientes
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Add servicio
     *
     * @param \Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios $servicio
     * @return Clientes
     */
    public function addServicio(\Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios $servicio)
    {
        $this->servicio[] = $servicio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove servicio
     *
     * @param \Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios $servicio
     */
    public function removeServicio(\Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios $servicio)
    {
        $this->servicio->removeElement($servicio);
    }

    /**
     * Get servicio
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getServicio()
    {
        return $this->servicio;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

**Servicio entity**

```
<?php

namespace Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Servicios
 */
class Servicios
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $nombre;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Servicios
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you are building the form in a bad way.
Your clientes type should be:

```
$builder
    ->add('nombre')
    ->add('servicio', 'entity', array(
        'class' => '/service/entity/namespace',
        'multiple' => true,
    ));
```

You will get a multiselect of servicios given an existent Cliente or a new one.

### Some tips

- Symfony2 entity is always Singular ( Cliente, Servicio )
- *ToMany relation variable should be plural ( $servicios, $clientes )

Comment: Thank you, it is working perfectly now. About the tips, I already know but the DB is from other old project and I just not updated names and stuf... But thank you! :)

Comment: One more thing (if you want I can make another question, but is related to this one).

In order to show in another form (another table with OneToOne relation to clientes and servicios) which servicios does clientes have, what must I do in my `otherTableType.php`? `->add('servicio');` shows every servicio and not cliente depending

Comment: You must create new method on Cliente as __toString(), for example, getCompleteClient(), and serialize all your data ( client name and all services separated by comma ), and when defines your new formType, you can define which property you want to show in select ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property )

Comment: Yeah I definitely don't know how to handle it to return X client services with a method into the Entity, only thing I can think is a repo with some join query but still don't know how to send to form...